# Sorting by length in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

Anyone have any idea how to sort number by length?

Ex : (11,111,122,12,2,13,21,15,211,22,213,2004)

I wanted the sorted array to be:

```
11
12
13
15
111
122
2
21
22
213
2004
```

Comment: `211` is missing from your desired output.

Answer (score 6):

The desired output seems to indicate you don't just want to sort by the number of digits, but rather first sort by the first digit and then by the length.

The desired output you show omits `211`, so I just put it where it belonged according to my understanding.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

my @source = (11, 111, 122, 12, 2, 13, 21, 15, 211, 22, 213, 2004);
my @desired = (11, 12, 13, 15, 111, 122, 2, 21, 22, 211, 213, 2004);

my @sorted =sort {
    substr($a, 0, 1) <=> substr($b, 0, 1) ||
    length($a) <=> length($b) || 
    $a <=> $b # thanks @ikegami
} @source;

is_deeply(\@sorted, \@desired, 'Sorted and desired are the same');
```

Comment: That could just as easily give 15,13,12,11,... as 11,12,13,15,... Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Thank you @Sinan, 
This is what I'm looking for. 
Actually, I want to implement it in hash function, the order number is as key. How I can do that.? thanks for your help

Comment: huh? Are you asking for `for (sort ... keys(%hash)) { $hash{$_} }`?

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @sorted =
   sort { substr($a,0,1) <=> substr($b,0,1) || $a <=> $b }
    @unsorted;
```

gives the order you requested. Or maybe you want

```
my @sorted =
   sort {  substr($a,0,1) <=> substr($b,0,1)
        || length($a) <=> length($b)
        || $a <=> $b }
   @unsorted;
```

If `211` wasn't missing from the output you provided, I could would tell you which one you want.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a so-called [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), which avoids recomputing the sort keys by temporarily associating them with the input items:

```
my @sorted =
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
    map { [ $_ => sprintf "%.1s%08x", $_, length ] }
    @source;
```

Comment: See also `List::Utils::sort_by`

Comment: You mean List::UtilsBy::sort_by, right? BTW, agreed, it definitely should be merged into List::Util/List::MoreUtils!

Answer (score 2):

This is provided by `List::UtilsBy::sort_by`

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( sort_by );

my @sorted = sort_by { sprintf "%.1s%08x", $_, length } @source;
```

It's much the same as the Schwartzian Transform solutions others have suggested, but wrapped in a neat abstraction.